# Turn off the monitor?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have windows 10 64 bit,and i spend a lot of time programming behind the screen.I need to take break from time to time,and limit the screen light/radiation from colliding with my head by making the screen turn black,as if turned off.

What i am capable of doing is dropping to login screen,but i need to see it BLACK to be relieved! What am really hoping to achieve is the black screen that you get when inactive for sometime.Can i do it programmatically?

Here's the code I've had so far:

```
#include <Windows.h>

#define KEY_DOWN(key) ((::GetAsyncKeyState(key) & 0x80000) ? 1 : 0)
#define KEY_UP(key)   ((::GetAsyncKeyState(key) & 0x80000) ? 0 : 1)

int main(void)
{
    // Hide the console window
    HWND hWnd;
    AllocConsole();
    hWnd = FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL);
    ShowWindow(hWnd, 0);

    //Press ctrl + alt + 'L' to lock / Press ctrl + 'E' to terminate the program
    while (1)
    {
        if (::GetAsyncKeyState('L') == -32767)
        {
            if (KEY_DOWN(VK_CONTROL) && KEY_DOWN(VK_MENU))
                LockWorkStation();
        }
        if (::GetAsyncKeyState('E') == -32767)
        {
            if (KEY_DOWN(VK_CONTROL))
                return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what about pure black screen saver?

Comment: @Lashane It just emits a low level of black colored light in that case. It's different than being off.

Comment: @Laurel I suppose this is meant under `What am really hoping to achieve is the black screen`

Comment: @Laurel I agree about black colored light, sometimes it is even more dangerous than light of different colors. In that case you would need special grounded tin foil hat, regular one may not work

Comment: Side notes: 1) use [`GetConsoleWindow()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683175.aspx) instead of `FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL)` so you don't find the wrong console window by mistake if multiple consoles are open. 2) per the `GetAsyncKeyState()` documentation, the least significant bit of the return value is not guaranteed to be accurate and should not be relied on, so change `== -32767` to either `& 0x8000` or `< 0` instead. 3) your `KEY_DOWN/UP()` macros are testing for `0x80000` when they should be testing for `0x8000` instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `SC_MONITORPOWER` parameter for the `WM_SYSCOMMAND` message to turn off the monitor:

```
SendMessage(handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, 2);
```

The argument `2` for the fourth parameter turns the monitor off.

See also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646360(v=vs.85).aspx